# React Navigation: Is there a way to add another instance of a screen on top of an existing instance of that screen in StackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

In my React Native app, I have a stack navigator with screens `A`, `B`, and `C`. Screen `A` displays info on a given user. I want to create a `switch user` button on screen `A` that will load another instance of screen `A`, but displaying info for a different user. If I use `this.props.navigation.navigate('A', {user: user2})` nothing happens because I'm already on screen `A`, ie. if you try to navigate to the same screen, it won't do it, even if the navigation params are different.

The reason I want to actually load a new instance of screen `A` rather than just staying on screen `A` and loading new user data is that when the user clicks `change user`, I want the visual effect that occurs when a new screen is added to the stack.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `navigation.replace('A', {user: user2});` to replace the top of the stack. Here's an expo snack demonstrating: https://snack.expo.io/d7NkeEmcz

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#push

You can also use StackActions for pushing new screen on top of current stack, as per documentation above example is:

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const pushAction = StackActions.push('screenA', { user: user2 });

navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
```